How can I make my code retry when Azure SQL goes down for maintenance?
I am currently trying to do a bugfix on a large piece of existing software. The issue occurs when the application is running a long process overnight and loses connection due to Azure SQL managed instance going down for maintenance. Currently, the process simply errors out and a user will have to start it again from scratch the next day and just hope the same thing doesn't happen the next night.
The app uses .NET 4.6.1, which I believe means it's using ADO.NET (but if I'm wrong about that or you want me to check in some way, let me know).
I feel like I'm getting mixed messages while trying to look up a solution to this. Should I already have access to some sort of built-in "retry" settings, or do I need to install an additional package? And in either of those cases, should I be able to fix the issue by just setting some values in one place - for example, where the connection string is defined - or will I have to code loops and/or try-catch logic each part of the code makes a connection or executes a query? (This would be literally hundreds of places.)
My connection string is stored in a config file. I have altered the contents like so:
<connectionStrings>
  <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
  <add name="myTenantName" connectionString="Data Source=thing1.thing2.thing3.azure.com,1234;Initial Catalog=My_DB_Name;Integrated Security=False;User=JohnSmith;Password=abc123;ConnectRetryCount=6;ConnectRetryInterval=10;ConnectTimeout=60;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

(Note: These are all fake values except for the providerName and the Connect___ values I'm trying to use.)
I have also tried using Connection Timeout instead of ConnectTimeout because the internet is giving me mixed messages about the correct name of that property.
This connection string is used every time the app tries to connect to the SQL database for anything, which is why I really hope that just making a change in one place can fix the issue.
Unfortunately, it currently does not fix the issue. I have tried disconnecting from the internet while the app was running a long process, and I have also tried taking the database offline using ALTER DATABASE [My_DB_Name] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE. In all cases (both of these disconnect methods and both versions of the connection string), the app's process just errors out and needs to be restarted.
Note: Ideally, I would like the retries to grow farther apart over time until a limit is reached, since I know some of these disconnects will be brief but some may not be. For example, retry after 30 secs, 1 minute, 5m, 10m, 30m, 60m, then give up. (If those numbers need to have a simple mathematical relationship - i.e., doubling - that's OK.)

To handle Azure SQL connection issues in your .NET 4.6.1 application, use Polly to implement robust retry logic with exponential backoff for transient faults. Ensure your connection string is properly configured, and refactor your database operations to utilize this retry mechanism for increased resilience.

You can also configure retry logic in your connection string by setting the ConnectRetryCount and ConnectRetryInterval properties. For example, you can set ConnectRetryCount=6 and ConnectRetryInterval=10 to retry 6 times with a 10-second delay between retries. However, it's important to note that this approach may not be sufficient for all scenarios and it's recommended to implement retry logic in your code as well.
